# Element will not display inline-block

Tags: css, erb

I'm trying to make a place my site logo and a horizontal navigation  element side by side, kind of like this: http://colorgrade.it/

For some reason, it still displays block, and a look at Chrome's javascript console shows that the navigation element has properties display:block, which seems to explain the problem.

However, I can't find the spot in my css that is causing this. The elements contributing to this property are ul, menu, and dir

A search for block in the file returns

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, section {
  display: block;
}
```

I also tried to add inline-block to the navigation element itself:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/navigation' , :style=>"display:inline-block;"%>
```

The navigation element looks like:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li>several li elements</li>
</ul>
```

Could someone explain why the two elements are not aligning side by side?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass the argument `style` to `render`, you need to apply the style option in the navigation partial (look for something like `navigation.html.erb`)

However, I would advise against using style attributes in your html, unless you really have to. In your case, using css in your stylesheet (look for `application.sass` if you use sass or `application.css` will do just fine.

If you want further advice, please post the html code of your navigation and your css code.

Comment: Thanks so much; I didn't think to apply the styling to partial.